# Spring security authentication server

Tags: java, spring, security

I am working on authentication service part of cloud app and I created the following security config class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
private final UserService userService;
private final JwtConstant jwtConstant;

@Autowired
public JwtSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder encoder, UserService userService, JwtConstant jwtConstant) {
    this.encoder= encoder;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.jwtConstant = jwtConstant;
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/signup").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}

private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConstant);
}
}
```

I am not sure about the chain methods of configure(HttpSecurity http) method. The authentication service will only receive "login" and "signup" requests.

- Should I remove authorizeRequests() method as I do not authorize anything?
- I am not sure about anyRequest().authenticated() part either if I really need it?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things that have to be changed, but first of all, you have to define a method that will provide jwt for each request and every request should provide an `AuthRequest` object that contains username and password :

```
@RestController
public class WelcomeController {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String generateToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUserName(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("inavalid username/password");
        }
        return jwtUtil.generateToken(authRequest.getUserName());
    }
}
```

and in the `UserDetailsService` you can make authentication as below :

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("tried to loging : " + username);
        if(!Objects.isNull(username) && !"".equals(username)){

            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByUserName(username);

            System.out.println(user.get());
            if(user.isPresent()){

                User userParam = user.get();
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userParam.getUserName(),
                        userParam.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user does not exists or empty !!");
    }
}
```

and for the configuration side :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);;
    }
}
```

for further information, you can follow my Github branch [Authnticaition sample](https://github.com/MrOdeh/webtoken)